# $\int_{0}^{t}\exp(c)\exp[-\exp(cx)]dx=?$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

$\int_{0}^{t}\exp(c)\exp[-\exp(cx)]dx=?$

I tried as:

$$\int_{0}^{t}\exp(c)\exp[-\exp(cx)]dx\\=\exp(c)[\frac{\exp[-\exp(cx)]}{-\exp(c)}]_{0}^{t}\\=-[\exp\{-\exp(cx)\}]_{0}^{t}\\=-[\exp\{-\exp(ct)\}-\exp(0)]\\=1-\exp\{-\exp(ct)\}.$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\exp(-\exp cx)}{-\exp c}&=\frac{\exp(-\exp cx)}{-\exp c}\frac{d}{dx}(-\exp cx)\\&=-c\exp(cx)\cdot\frac{\exp(-\exp cx)}{-\exp c}\\&\ne\exp(-\exp cx).\end{align}$$The substitution $u=-e^{cx}$ lets you write your integral in terms of [a special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), as$$\frac1ce^c(\operatorname{Ei}(-e^{ct})-\operatorname{Ei}(-1)).$$